# Blocklist [operations-research] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag `[operations-research]` is a site-name tag which does not appear to have any use and has no usage description. It is currently used on 8 questions, down from 18 originally before I recently began to remove it from a few of those questions (to avoid a huge edit bump). It is mostly used by new users, as some of them may be unfamiliar with the tagging system.

I am in favour of its being [blocklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355815/whats-a-disallowed-tag-called-now/355816#355816), which means that the tag will not be able to be used in the future. As this action requires Community Moderator intervention, there has to be consensus from our community before it can be done. Your opinions welcome!

Comment: Even when the site first started, I had a hard time deciding where this tag should be used. I second your proposal.

Comment: I third the proposal.

Comment: Should be blocked as [intrinsic tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62183/241919) in the first place~

Comment: Using code for non-code text messes with screen readers, can you please edit that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added this to the site's blocklist. [or] was added as an intrinsic tag as Andrew T mentioned, but [operations-research] was overlooked. Thanks for the request!

Comment: Thanks for your handling this!

Answer (score 3):

**Blocklist**  [operations-research](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operations-research)

It is irrelevant on this site.